# How to run a bidirectional ESC with pigpio library

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4. I have managed to run a unidirectional ESC using the following code:

```
import time
import pigpio

ESC=13

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
   exit()

# step 1 to arm the esc
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, 2000)
time.sleep(1)

# step 2 to arm the esc
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(ESC, 1000)
time.sleep(1)

# set motor speed
pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, 1100)
time.sleep(10)

pi.stop()
```

But I need bidirectional movement so I've decided that I'm going to buy a [bidirectional ESC](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Brushless-Bidirectional-Electronic-Controller-Control/dp/B0B6PH713X). What PWM values do I need to send to the ESC so it can run in reverse?

Comment: `What PWM values do I need to send to the ESC so it can run in reverse?` is a question about the ESC ... it is not a question about the Raspberry Pi ... as such, it does not belong here ... please post it at https://drones.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you posted specs of the ESC someone may know, but as the link lacks any meaningful specs no one can say. Either way it is not a Pi question.

Comment: @Milliways, it is a pi question since I'm using a raspberry pi to send pwm signals to the ESC

Comment: Are you suggesting that the ESC would need different PWM values on an Arduino or other hardware?

Comment: No but the code to send the PWM signals will be different

Answer (score 0):

Typically a bidirectional ESC is controlled by the pulse width in microseconds.

```
500µs full speed backwards
1000µs half speed backwards
1500µs stop
2000µs half speed forwards
2500µs full speed forwards
```

The actual values will depend on the ESC model.